# 3 conditions are not acceptable in if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Declare the process is out of control if `Y>=UCL1`, `Y<=LCL1`  (`UCL1` and `LCL1` control limits are called the outer control limits).

Declare the process is in control if `LCL2<=Y<=UCL2` (and are called the inner control limits). However if `UCL2<Y<=UCL1` or `LCL1<Y<=LCL2`, go to step I and repeat the process. Now it is full R code please check it and tell me why is not working. when I have run this code I do not get any results.

```
ld=0.20;n=10; ssize=10000
p0=0.5;
k1=runif(ssize,0,3.2);k1
k2=runif(ssize,0,3.2);k2
mu.x=asin(sqrt(0.5));
var.x=1/(4*n)
M=c(); ARL=c();ARL=370;
shift=c(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.50,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95)
UCL1=mu.x+k1*sqrt(var.x)*sqrt((ld/(2-ld)));UCL1
LCL1=mu.x-k1*sqrt(var.x)*sqrt((ld/(2-ld)));LCL1
UCL2=mu.x+k2*sqrt(var.x)*sqrt((ld/(2-ld)));UCL2
LCL2=mu.x-k2*sqrt(var.x)*sqrt((ld/(2-ld)));LCL2
for(l in 1:length(shift))
{
  p1=shift[l]
  x=c();rl=c();

  for(j in 1:10000){

    for(t in 1:10000){

      x[t]=asin(sqrt(rbinom(1,n,p1)/n))
      if(t==1){M[t]=ld*x[t]+(1-ld)*mu.x} else{M[t]=ld*x[t]+(1-ld)*M[t-1]}       # new Modified EWMA Statistic

      if((M[t]>UCL2 & M[t]<LCL2) | (M[t]>UCL1 & M[t]<UCL2) | (M[t]>LCL2 & M[t]<LCL1)) { 
        rl[j]=t
      }   
      else{ 
        rl[j]=0
      }
    }
  }
  ARL[l]=mean(rl)


}

print(cbind(shift,ARL,LCL1,LCL2,UCL1,UCL2))
```

Comment: you were missing heaps of brackets. I edited the code to include them. once its approved try that code. Also please include a sample of your data, and any error messages

Comment: it is not working. can I send you full R code? then you can modify it. @RAB

Comment: what do you want your output to be? you UCL1/2 are just numeric vectors...that seems like a poor way to structure your data. How about putting everything into 1 data.frame and starting the code from scratch? If you can create a data.frame and show the output you want I can help you get ther

Comment: actually, I want to get the ARL0=370 when k1 > k2 and p0=0.5 and also want to get the ARL1 values by using the p1=shifted values @RAB

Comment: yeah...i don't really know what you mean. You need to think about restructuring your data into 1 dataframe with each variable (`ARL0/ARL1/k1/k2` etc) as a different column. Once you have that you can use `ifelse` or `for` loops to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Okay one major issue is the loop variable `j` is never defined. Also you should enclose your for loop with curly braces.

Like this:

```
for(j in 1:10000){
  for(t in 1:10000){
    if(Y>UCL2 | (Y<LCL2 & Y>UCL1) | (Y<UCL2 & Y>LCL2) | Y<LCL1) { 
      rl[j]=t
    }   
    else{ 
      rl[j]=0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know 3 condition is not acceptable in R. as above I mentioned (if LCL2<=Y<=UCL2 we said process is in control and if UCL2<Y<=UCL1 or LCL1<Y<=LCL2, go to step I and repeat the process.) can you described how I can write this in R with if else condition? @John Siryj